# Javascript build fails

Tags: codenameone

I tried to do a javascript build with an existing working project but it gives me a build error like below, any idea ?

The project is working for Android and IOS, I did the build without any changes of settings or whatever

*Full stack Trace :*

```
Executing: /home/ec2-user/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java -Dretrolambda.inputDir=/tmp/build4395325875721494407xxx/tmpClasses -Dretrolambda.classpath=/tmp/build4395325875721494407xxx/tmpClasses:/tmp/temp6791530583283105825.jar -Dretrolambda.outputDir=/tmp/build4395325875721494407xxx/tmpClasses_retrolamda -Dretrolambda.bytecodeVersion=49 -jar /tmp/temp3309944789126593083.jar Retrolambda 2.0.3
Bytecode version: 49 (Java 5)
Default methods: false
Input directory: /tmp/build4395325875721494407xxx/tmpClasses
Output directory: /tmp/build4395325875721494407xxx/tmpClasses_retrolamda
Classpath: /tmp/build4395325875721494407xxx/tmpClasses:/tmp/temp6791530583283105825.jar
Executing: /home/ec2-user/javascript/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/mvn -e clean package [INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for nl.aalease.apps:Main:war:1.0
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for ca.weblite:codename1-core:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/lib/CodenameOne.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 24, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for ca.weblite:codename1-factory:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/lib/Factory.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 32, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for ca.weblite:codename1-core-hello:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/lib/app.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 40, column 25
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Main 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Main ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Main ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Main ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 50 source files to /tmp/build4395325875721494407xxx/target/classes
[WARNING] /tmp/build4395325875721494407xxx/src/main/java/com/codename1/impl/html5/Stub.java: /tmp/build4395325875721494407xxx/src/main/java/com/codename1/impl/html5/Stub.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[WARNING] /tmp/build4395325875721494407xxx/src/main/java/com/codename1/impl/html5/Stub.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[WARNING] /tmp/build4395325875721494407xxx/src/main/java/com/codename1/teavm/ext/localforage/LocalForage.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[WARNING] /tmp/build4395325875721494407xxx/src/main/java/com/codename1/teavm/ext/localforage/LocalForage.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Main ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /tmp/build4395325875721494407xxx/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Main ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ Main ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- teavm-maven-plugin:0.3.0-cn1-039:build-javascript (web-client) @ Main ---
[INFO] Preparing classpath for JavaScript generation
[INFO] Using the following classpath for JavaScript generation: /tmp/build4395325875721494407xxx/lib/CodenameOne.jar:/tmp/build4395325875721494407xxx/lib/Factory.jar:/tmp/build4395325875721494407xxx/lib/app.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/org/teavm/teavm-classlib/0.3.0-cn1-039/teavm-classlib-0.3.0-cn1-039.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/org/teavm/teavm-platform/0.3.0-cn1-039/teavm-platform-0.3.0-cn1-039.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/org/teavm/teavm-core/0.3.0-cn1-039/teavm-core-0.3.0-cn1-039.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-debug-all/5.0.3/asm-debug-all-5.0.3.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/com/carrotsearch/hppc/0.6.1/hppc-0.6.1.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/com/jcraft/jzlib/1.1.3/jzlib-1.1.3.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.7/joda-time-2.7.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/org/teavm/teavm-jso/0.3.0-cn1-039/teavm-jso-0.3.0-cn1-039.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/org/teavm/teavm-dom/0.3.0-cn1-039/teavm-dom-0.3.0-cn1-039.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/org/mitre/dsmiley/httpproxy/smiley-http-proxy-servlet/1.6/smiley-http-proxy-servlet-1.6.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.4/httpclient-4.3.4.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3.2/httpcore-4.3.2.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar:/tmp/build4395325875721494407xxx/target/classes
[INFO] Building JavaScript file
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:16 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-02-09T05:28:02-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/839M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.teavm:teavm-maven-plugin:0.3.0-cn1-039:build-javascript (web-client) on project Main: Unexpected error occured: -1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.teavm:teavm-maven-plugin:0.3.0-cn1-039:build-javascript (web-client) on project Main: Unexpected error occured
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unexpected error occured
at org.teavm.maven.BuildJavascriptMojo.execute(BuildJavascriptMojo.java:261)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:400)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:413)
at org.teavm.javascript.Renderer.visitStatements(Renderer.java:2035)
at org.teavm.javascript.Renderer.visit(Renderer.java:931)
at org.teavm.javascript.ast.ConditionalStatement.acceptVisitor(ConditionalStatement.java:48)
at org.teavm.javascript.Renderer.visitStatements(Renderer.java:2035)
at org.teavm.javascript.Renderer.visit(Renderer.java:1059)
at org.teavm.javascript.ast.BlockStatement.acceptVisitor(BlockStatement.java:34)
at org.teavm.javascript.Renderer.visitStatements(Renderer.java:2032)
at org.teavm.javascript.Renderer.visit(Renderer.java:1059)
at org.teavm.javascript.ast.BlockStatement.acceptVisitor(BlockStatement.java:34)
at org.teavm.javascript.Renderer.visitStatements(Renderer.java:2032)
at org.teavm.javascript.Renderer.visit(Renderer.java:910)
at org.teavm.javascript.ast.SequentialStatement.acceptVisitor(SequentialStatement.java:34)
at org.teavm.javascript.Renderer$MethodBodyRenderer.visit(Renderer.java:752)
at org.teavm.javascript.ast.AsyncMethodNode.acceptVisitor(AsyncMethodNode.java:51)
at org.teavm.javascript.Renderer.renderBody(Renderer.java:604)
at org.teavm.javascript.Renderer.renderMethodBodies(Renderer.java:404)
at org.teavm.javascript.Renderer.render(Renderer.java:302)
at org.teavm.vm.TeaVM.build(TeaVM.java:441)
at org.teavm.tooling.TeaVMTool.generate(TeaVMTool.java:299)
at org.teavm.maven.BuildJavascriptMojo.execute(BuildJavascriptMojo.java:256)
... 21 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: there is an array out of bounds in Renderer.java line 2035.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be an issue with the current implementation of [TeaVM](http://teavm.org) that we are using for the [JavaScript port](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/javascript-port.html).

We are in the process of updating the VM to the latest version which will hopefully resolve that issue.

I've added [an issue](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1677) to our issue tracker to track the status more effectively.